# How to close a Java GUI application in x seconds?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I need some help regarding the Java GUI I developed using NetBeans. I want the functionality
where the user clicks on a button to exit the application. Instead of immediately exiting, I would like a message to pop up saying "Your job was submitted and this window will close in 10s". And maybe show a count down from 10 to 0.

Comment: Is there a reason for this other than to annoy the user?

Comment: i have looked at the following code:long test = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(test >= (pastTime + 15*1000)) { //multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds
  doSomething();
}

Comment: javax.swing.Timer comes to mind (and has worked well for me in similar situation). What have you tried? Edit: don't use your System.currentTimeMillis method. Again, use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Below is the solution to my question.Hope it helps someone else as well. Guys cheer up and be helpful...someday you will need the same help..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for that: (Thanks to Ko Wey at 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/341814/GUI/java/JOptionPane-Timeout)

```
# //file CustomDialog.java    
# import javax.swing.*;  
# import java.awt.*;  
# import java.awt.event.*;  
#    
# class CustomDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener,Runnable{  
#    
# private JButton jButton_Yes = null;  
# private JButton jButton_NO = null;  
# private boolean OK = false;  
# private Thread thread = null;  
# private int seconds = 0;  
# private final int max = 30;//max number of seconds   
#    
# public CustomDialog(Frame frame){  
# super(frame,true);//modal  
# setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);  
#    
# Box hBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();  
#    
# jButton_Yes = new JButton("Yes");  
# jButton_Yes.addActionListener(this);  
#    
# jButton_NO = new JButton("NO");  
# jButton_NO.addActionListener(this);  
#    
# JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("How are you?");  
#    
# Container cont = getContentPane();  
# cont.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cont,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  
# cont.add(jLabel);  
# hBox.add(Box.createGlue());  
# hBox.add(jButton_Yes);  
# hBox.add(jButton_NO);  
# cont.add(hBox);  
#    
# pack();  
# thread = new Thread(this);  
# thread.start();  
# setVisible(true);  
# }  
#    
# public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
# if (e.getSource()==jButton_Yes)  
# OK = true;  
# if (e.getSource()==jButton_NO)  
# OK = false;  
# setVisible(false);  
# }  
#    
# public void run(){  
# while(seconds < max){  
# seconds++;  
# setTitle("OK? "+seconds);  
# try{  
# Thread.sleep(1000);  
# }catch (InterruptedException exc){  
# };  
# }  
# setVisible(false);  
# }  
#    
# public boolean isOk(){return OK;}  
#    
# public static void main(String[] args){//testing  
# CustomDialog cd = new CustomDialog(new JFrame());  
# System.out.println(cd.isOk());  
# cd = null;  
# System.exit(0);  
# }  
#    
# }//end
```

Answer (score 3):

[`JOptionTest`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.help/msg/3b09c5a8719e35d7) is an example that uses [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Answer (score 1):

For information on how to implement Java dialogue check out the tutorial [How to Make Dialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). If you want to perform some task before closing the app, you could display [progress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) in your dialogue window.